# Windows profile getting updated at boot

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

I have a RDP server (win 2016 server) with 30/35 local users. I have a default profile that i configured nicely, but of course, the default profile copy its settings only when a new user get created.

What i need is that when i change the default profile, all the users copy default profile upon login, so i don't have to go manually and update each and every existing users.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: That's simply not how that works.  Once the default profile is copied, all changes happen per user.  Make changes after that using Group policy.

Comment: thx for your answer, so couldn't it possible that all user get their profile from let's say user1 account, so i can only update user1 and upon reboot, they would get updated, its so complicated to update users, between their chrome plugin, firefox plugin, firefox portable plugin etc..

Comment: No... it isn't possible.

Comment: You could use a Mandatory Profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i achieved it somehow by doing the following:

**step 1)** Defprof

**step2 )** copy manually AppData\Local to Default Profile (chrome plugins etc..)

**step 3)** Powershell script that delete and recreate all users at boot. (task scheduler)

So now i can burn my AMI and being sure that all new users got the latest default settings.

It was a pain, but it works, so i guess i'll stick to it ;)

Thanks anyway for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want using profiles